# Sharing a repository on a dual-boot between Ubuntu and Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, repository

I just recently set my computer up to dual-boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I added a shared partition for music, pictures etc... I was wondering, is it feasible to have a code repository that is shared on the common partition? ie when I'm running Windows, I can control/update it and also the same while in Ubuntu.

Is a particular repository system adept at that? Or is it too much trouble?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't tried it but you can use SubVersion on a Fat32 partition shared between both systems. The only problem is that SubVersion will try to do a "chmod" command in Ubuntu and if the drive is owned by root then that causes an issue. You can get around that by mounting it as your Ubuntu user.

Some info about that at this link: [SVN Forum](http://www.svnforum.org/2017/viewtopic.php?t=1490).